# Is a non-combat character damaging in a party?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, non-combat

I'm trying to build a rogue/cleric based on having a ton of proficiencies and languages with high mental stats (especially charisma). The problem is, I'm worried I will not be an effective PC in the party, as the campaign is about 50/50 combat and roleplaying. I can give fairly minor buffs and do a small amount of sneak attack damage, but we already have a bard and rogue that can outclass me. The reasons I don't straight up take bard is,

1. We already have 2 bards.
2. I don't want to play a primary spellcasting class (only going 4 levels in cleric).
3. I'm trying to build something along the lines of "corrupt politician/spy" and rogue is built for that.
4. Rogue and cleric give me all the proficiencies and languages I need.

I don't really want to damage the party's combat strength as I was more helpful in combat with my last character. So, is it fair to the other players to make a non-combat character that cant help much in fighting in a campaign with a fair amount of combat?

Comment: What does your group say? Or are you looking for the way to pitch this *to* your group? What you've outlined reads a bit like "can I make a character poor at combat but not bring down the average?" Which has the obvious answer "no." So I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "viable."

Comment: "Viable" is one of those words that is used to mean completely different things by different people. When you use "viable" in this post, what do *you* mean?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I suppose I mean "enough to pull my weight in the group"

Comment: Are you speaking specifically about in combat viability? You could surely be used to avoid combat, but maybe you're not interested in that? it sounds like you might already have your answer, since you noted that the campaign is about 50/50. Are you not excelling in the other 50 where your party might be holding YOU back?

Comment: @PremierBromanov The party has two bards, so low charisma is definitely not an issue. The main reason I'm worrying is because we have 2 bards, a fighter, an arcane trickster rogue who rarely uses sneak attack and a pacifistic cleric, so every bit of damage helps as we only have 2 real damage dealers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to justify my thematic spell selections to other players saying they're underpowered?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68368/how-to-justify-my-thematic-spell-selections-to-other-players-saying-theyre-unde)

Comment: Also, doesn't rogue/cleric + ton of proficiencies + high charisma = bard? Can I ask for what reasons you're trying to hit all those notes without choosing the Bard class? (I ask because this may point us to the strengths you *are* building which *aren't* native to the rest of your party.)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't go straight rogue?  They have a ton of proficiencies, and you can just take the Linguist feat for the languages.  What do you actually get from Cleric?

Comment: @KyleW Knowledge domain gives 2 languages and 2 proficiencies with double proficiency and a class ability that can give you a proficiency

Comment: Have you found that you are in fact not helping? Or havent you done combat with the group? What is your approach during combat?

Comment: @PremierBromanov I stated that I am making this character, so I have not had an opportunity to play it yet.

Comment: Have you folded in how to use the "help" action in your plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Talk to your DM

Ultimately, your DM is the one designing encounters, so he/she needs to know that you're playing a non-combat focused character. Your DM can ease back on the encounters if necessary and provide options for your character to do what he does best out of combat. You should also find out if the type of campaign your DM is running is appropriate for this type of character. We can postulate about the possibilities of your party all day, but it's meaningless without knowledge of your DM and your campaign. This doesn't mean "tell us about your campaign", this means "talk to your DM". Ask your DM this same question, and that will be a better answer than any we can give.

Either way, I'll take a crack at answering your question, but the number 1 thing you need to do is talk to your DM about this.

> So, is it fair to the other players to make a non-combat character
>   that cant help much in fighting in a campaign with a fair amount of
>   combat?

### Absolutely, but...

You should get on the same page with your group. Your character is one that excels at the out of combat stuff, so you need to make sure they're on board with you being a stand-out character when not fighting and a behind-the-scenes character when you are fighting. Your character is also one that can prevent combat from happening if you so desire, so you should find out if your group wants to do that ever.

### Speculation about your group

Looking at your group, you've got 2 bards, 1 rogue, and 1 rogue/cleric (you). Your group is not suited for brawling very much, like a group with fighters, barbarians, and/or paladins would be. Bards are good support that can deal out some ranged damage if they choose to build that way and rogues are good at dealing damage to distracted or unaware targets. So if you're playing a non-combat character, you may run into trouble.

What does this mean?

Your party needs to play to their strengths. You can be a valuable asset as a support, someone that heals, controls enemies, and helps friendlies. You are likely not good at damage, so the rest of your party should be, or it may not work. Having only 1 melee with 3 supports (2 bards and you) might not work well against heavy hitting targets. Your party's strength lies in avoiding combat and surprising targets when combat is necessary and controlling targets to make them less scary. If you focus on doing that, you should be alright. Grab spells that help your group and use your sneak attack when its available (you can do this at range too), because it's a pretty good chunk of damage no matter who you are. A diplomat can still carry a big stick.

Again, talk to your DM and find out if this is feasible.

Comment: I feel like one thing that's missing in the "talk to DM" portion is "this party isn't good at combat, so try not to get into combat so much. Why are things going 50/50?"